# php profile with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a login system where the user by inserting email and password can login to the application. After the user creating his profile page and sets his timetable the following piece of code prints on screen his profile, without any errors. This is the code that prints the profile page:

```
<?php
   if(  isset($_GET['email']) === true  &&  empty($_GET['email']) === false  ){

    $email = $_GET['email'];

  if(user_exists($email) === true) {

        $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
        $profile_data = user_data($user_id,'name','surname','email');
?>

<h1><font size="5"><?php echo $profile_data['name'];?> <?php echo $profile_data['surname']; ?> </font></h1>

<a href="profile_timetable.php" >Timetable</a>

<?php

}else {
    echo 'Sorry, that user does not exist!';
}
  }else{
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit();
   }
```

I am also having a .htaccess file which is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /work/profile.php?email=$1
```

And this is the code that prints the timetable page:

```
<?

if(  isset($_GET['email']) === true  &&  empty($_GET['email']) === false  ){


$email = $_GET['email'];

    if(user_exists($email) === true) {

       $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);

       $profile_data_timetable = $user_data_profile_timetable($user_id,'hour_start_1','minute_start_1','hour_finish_1','minute_finish_1','activity_1');

?>

<font size="5"> 
    <?php echo $user_data_profile_timetable['hour_start_1']; ?> 
    <?php echo $user_data_profile_timetable['minute_start_1']; ?> 
    <?php echo $user_data_profile_timetable['hour_finish_1']; ?> 
    <?php echo $user_data_profile_timetable['minute_finish_1']; ?> 
    <?php echo $user_data_profile_timetable['activity_1']; ?> 
</font>

<?php
  }else {
echo 'Sorry, that user does not exist!';
}
 }else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
 }
```

My problem is that if I click on "timetable link" to get the user's timetable, I get just an empty screen (probably redirects to index.php which is an empty page). How can I fix this so that the link will work and prints the user's timetable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo should edit the link to resend the email

the link is going to `profile_timetable.php` but it should go to `profile_timetable.php?email=fooo@foo.fo`

you can try this:

```
<a href="profile_timetable.php?email=<?php echo $email; ?>" >Timetable</a>
```

i notice that you don't check if submitted email haves a valid format, be carefull about injections!

you can simply use `if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` to check email format or use a REGEX